# Align Div in middle of page?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my `<div>` element in the center of the page.

I am using the following code which works if the height of `<div class='box'>` is less than 600px, if the height increases to 1000px then it stretches out to the top and bottom of the page.

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box"><div class="div1"></div><div class="div2"></div><div class="div3"></div></div>
    </body>
</html>


<style>
    .box{
        height:600px;
        width:960px;
        margin:auto;
        border:1px solid #000;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        left:0;
    }
    .div1{
        height:100px;
        width:100%;
        background:red;
        position:relative;
        top:0;

    }
    .div2{
        height:100px;
        width:100%;
        background:red;
        position:relative;
        margin-top:60px;

    }
    .div3{
        height:100px;
        width:100%;
        background:red;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;

    }
    </style>
```

I have put together the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjj8ujqb/1/) but it doesn't seem to reflect what my browser shows. My browser displays the div at a  viewport of 600px as below:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|                      |
|                      |
|          _           |
|      {  Box  }       |
|          -           |
|                      |  < Browser window
- - - - - - - - - - - -
```

If the height of ` increases to 1000px the following results:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|          -           |
|                      |
|                      |
|      {  Box  }       |
|                      |
|          _           |  < Browser window
- - - - - - - - - - - -
```

What should be changed?

Comment: Is there a way you can demonstrate the problem? It's difficult to tell what you're asking without being able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: you should use relative position with margin bla bla not top, bottom etc.
using absolute value will draw the box as wide and high as the sized you manage

Comment: If someone downvotes they should leave a comment as to why. I think downvotes are great when we can all learn. But to down vote without saying why is not constructive.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep `.div2` in the middle of the container, even if the height changes, is to add this CSS:

```
   .div2{
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        background: lightblue;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -50px;
    }
```

[Heres your updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjj8ujqb/4/). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To do this position your container relative.

Then your box position it absolute.

Make the top: 50%;
Add a margin-top: (-) (box height * .5)

Make the left: 50%;
Add a margin-left: (-) (box width * .5)

Here is the code:

```css
.box{
        height:100vh;
        width:100vw;
        margin:auto;
        border:1px solid #000;
        position:relative;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        left:0;
    }
    .centered-object{
        height:50px;
        width:50px;
        top:50%;
        margin-top: -25px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -25px;
        background:red;
        
        
    }
```

```html
<div class="box">
    
<div class="centered-object"></div>

</div>
```

Let me know if that makes sense to you or if you need more explaining.

Here is your updated fiddle if you prefer that: http://jsfiddle.net/pjj8ujqb/3/

No matter how big you make your window the box always stays center.

Comment: Do you understand the OP's question? Because I don't.

Comment: I thought he was saying he wants a square in the center of the page.  But I was confused when I saw his fiddle cause his fiddle has 3 bars and none of them are centered.  His first sentence is "am having some problems here getting my div to align correctly in the middle of the page."  So I figured if I just show him how to center he can go from there and would lead to other questions to help him further.

Comment: I'm confused, too. It seems that he's already got the centering working: "I am using the following code which works...".

Comment: Well I figured my answer will get him started and I would edit it as he asked questions.. but he has not asked anything yet.

Comment: Why did someone downvote without leaving a comment. How am I supposed to learn or improve without leaving constructive feedback on why you downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. the problem i was having was the box div was moving of the page when the height increased, this was easily fixed by adding a top and bottom margin like so:

```
   .box{
        height:800px;
        width:960px;
        border:1px solid #000;
        position:absolute;
        margin : 5% auto 5% auto;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
    }
```